# RegEx issue in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following RegEx:

```
/[a-zA-Z\d ']{1,30}/
```

and the following string:

```
some text'&&
```

Now, that RegEx returns true on the string. I suppose that it matches the part without "&&". I'd like to ask how can I limit characters to alphanumeric characters, including space and apostrophes as the RegEx from above writes.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression matching for entire string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571226/regular-expression-matching-for-entire-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anchor your regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d ']{1,30}$/
```

`^` means "start of string" and `$` means "end of string" so adding those markers forces the regex to either match the entire string or not at all.