# how to use preg_match to check whole text

Tags: php, regex

Hi i have a problem with preg_match function.
i want to check whole text against pattern and return true if whole text matched with pattern and false for not matched or partially matched with pattern but i can't do this with php preg_match function.
for example i use bellow func to check if input is digit or no.

```
if(preg_match("/[\d]/","99ab") return true; else return false;
```

above code return true but i want to this return false.
and other regex that i want to check is users first name and last name with preg_match.
and another regex for phone numbers with this format (000) 000-0000.
please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression matching for entire string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571226/regular-expression-matching-for-entire-string)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the pattern like this:

```
"/^[\d]+$/"
```

Remember that:

- ^: means the start of the string
- $: means the end of the string

Comment: can you give me regex for (000) 000-0000

Comment: is this true?
if(preg_match('/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$/',"(112) 000-0000"))

Comment: @fireboy: Brackets (`(` and `)`) are used in regular expressions for grouping, so you need to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ^ to indicate the start of the string and $ for the end

```
if (preg_match("/^[\d]+$/","99ab")) return true; 
else return false;
```

Comment: ok
for above regex this work but i cant use your suggestion for below regex for check phone number with this format (000) 000-0000
if(preg_match('/^(\d{3}) \d{3}-\d{4}$/',"(000) 000-0000"))return true; else return false;
this function return false!

Comment: I believe you'll need to escape the brackets: e.g. `/^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4}$/`

Comment: thanks
i have another problem with users first name and last name.  for example i use this regex for first name ("/^[a-zA-Z]$/","Alex") but this doesn't work wit preg_match!. for full name which regex is true? regex for alex delpiero? that start with char end with char and space between first name and last name.

Comment: `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/","Alex")` returns false because you're only checking for a single a-zA-Z character, e.g. 'A' would return true. You need to match multiple characters `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/","Alex")`

Comment: i add + before $ and above regex work for alex! like this if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/","alex")) return true;

Comment: work this method for java script ^ for start and $ for end? or no

Comment: i write this regex for full name is this ok?
  if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$/","ali a2x"))
   echo "ok";

Comment: i can't use this regex with spry framework(javascript library).
my regex is.
/^[\u0600-\u06FF]+\s[\u0600-\u06FF]+$/