# how to write an exact pattern matching in php

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I'm looking for the syntax for pattern matching or a function in PHP that returns true only if the pattern in the string occurs once. I only found the function `preg_match`. But in case `preg_match('/[A-Za-z]{3}/', "asdf")` it returns `true`, because the given string contains the pattern. I need the logic like it works in the html input tag in the attribute pattern. More or less symbols should return `false`.

Comment: Showing some sample inputs and expected behavior is so helpful. From rest of your question it seems you need to anchor your regex: `^[A-Za-z]{3}$`.

Comment: You also don't need a regex http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php could do it

Comment: stating this is a duplicate should be done with a link to the actual solution, at least after this https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: @fab2s I stopped reading that rant at `women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups`. Nothing is known about users on this site other than their code. The post started to have some valid points then immediately drove off a cliff. Additionally the first link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058258/how-to-use-preg-match-to-check-whole-text, does give the solution. Anchors are/were needed (as noted by the OP `thank you a lot!`).