# PHP regex with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if a variable contains only alphabetical characters and apostrophes (') and dashes (-) and white space ( ) characters. How can do I this with `preg_match()` in PHP?

I have /[^a-zA-Z'-\s]/i and it solved without apostroph.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Neither `preg_march` nor `preg_math` will be of any aid to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression matching for entire string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571226/regular-expression-matching-for-entire-string)

Comment: I am almost certain you're not ACTUALLY looking for a string which has all of: alphanumeric characters, apostrophes, whitespace, AND dashes. Unless you have a *really* oddly specific search. Also, your current regex will only return true if your string has a character you DON'T want.

Comment: I am, Palladium. I have some string like "goal", "goal-", "o'henry", "colo colo".. And I do not want to get strings like "at&t", "4you", ":)" etc.

Comment: See, "goal" doesn't contain alphanumeric characters AND an apostrophe AND whitespace AND dashes. That's what I meant - you're not looking for all those things at the same time. And that's what my regex was for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^[\s\pL'-]+$/',$string)
```

This is the way I'd do it

//EDIT

Maybe if you have a minimum count of letters, use this:

```
preg_match("/^[\s\pL'-]{5,}$/",$string) //{x,} ---> x is your min number
```

Comment: `\w` also matches digits and underscores.

Comment: ok, sry, my mistake, thought it would be digits too and forgot about underscores. maybe \pL instead of \w, or does it match those too?

Comment: \pL should be fine. Also, a quantifier after the character class, since as it stands it'll only match one-character strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/^[a-zA-Z'\-\s]*$/` as your regex string. Note that this regex will also match blank strings.

Comment: Nope, I tried /[^a-zA-Z'\-\s]/i and it solved without apostroph.