# Function to validate username and password not working

Tags: php, validation, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression matching for entire string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571226/regular-expression-matching-for-entire-string)

On my form page, I am trying to make it only accept alphanumeric characters for my username and password and require that they be from 6 to 15 characters. When I type in invalid data, it will insert it into the database rather than throw the user error that I defined in my CheckAlNum function.

functions.php

```
function checkAlNum($whichField) 
{
    if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST[$whichField])){
        if ( (!count(strlen($whichField) >= 6)) OR (!count(strlen($whichField) <= 15 ))) {
            $message1 = '<p> Username and password must be between 6 and 15 characters </p>';
                return user_error($message1);
        }
        else{       
            return true;
        }           
    }

    else {
        $message = '<p>Username and password can only be numbers or letters</p>';
            return user_error($message);
     }


 }
```

Form.php

```
        if (count($_POST) > 0) {

           //Validate the inputs
            $errorMessages = array();

            //Validate the username   
            $item5 = checkAlNum('username');
            if($item5 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item5;
            }

            //Validate the password
            $item6 = checkAlNum('password');
            if($item6 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item6;
            }

            //Validate the firstName and lastName
            $item1 = checkNameChars('firstName');
            if ($item1 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item1;

            }

            $item2 = checkNameChars('lastName');
            if ($item2 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item2;

            }   

            //Validate the office name
            $item3 = checkOfficeChars('office');
            if ($item3 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item3;

            }

            //Validate the phone number 
            $item4 = validate_phone_number('phoneNumber');
            if($item4 !== true) {
                $errorMessages[] = $item4;
            }  


            //Check to see if anything failed
            if (count($errorMessages) == 0) {

                $newEmployee = new Person;
                    $newEmployee -> insert();

            }

            else { //Else, reprint the form along with some error messages
                echo "<h2><span>Error</span>: </h2>";

                foreach($errorMessages as $msg) {
                    echo "<p>" . $msg . "</p>";
              }
            }
        }  

        ?>
```

I've tried playing around with the nesting of the if-else statements of the checkAlNum function and also the regex (although I'm pretty sure the regex is right). Maybe I'm just missing something really silly?

Comment: by the way, I DID require functions.php in the Form class

Comment: You can incorporate the length check into the regex, eg: `[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkAlNum($whichField) 
{
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{6,15}$/i', $_POST[$whichField])) {
        return true;          
    }
    else {
        $message = '<p>Username and password can only be numbers or letters, 6-15 characters long</p>';
            return user_error($message);
     }
}
```

Without the `^` and `$` anchors, your regex only checks whether there are alphanumerics anywhere in the field, not that the whole thing is alphanumeric. And changing `+` to `{6,15}` implements the length check here, so you can remove that extra check in your code.

Comment: Thanks all! Barmar's answer worked like a charm. And I'll keep those tips in mind. The only reason I went with if statements in the first place was because I'm bad at regular expressions and figured it would be an easier fix for my level of experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second if statement is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
if ( !( (!count(strlen($whichField) >= 6)) OR (!count(strlen($whichField) <= 15 )) ) ) {
// ... do something
}
```

This is due to De Morgan Rule which states

A AND B = !( !A OR !B )

In any  case, I would not do my checks this way, strucurally you will end up with too many nested if statements that are hard to maintain and make your code look unpretty. Try avoiding nested conditions in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Barmar's answer is the best. But if you want to keep your if statement to check string length, you need to remove the `count()` as you are already checking the length using `strlen()`.

```
if ( (!(strlen($whichField) >= 6)) OR (!(strlen($whichField) <= 15 ))) {
```